# Fullscreen animation effects with CoreAnimation?

Tags: cocoa, animation

I'm trying to perform some fullscreen animation effects like moving/scaling windows and effects like how files "jump" into the download folder in Safari.

My first attempt was to make windows with a NSImageView content view and use CoreAnimation to move the window around the screen. This failed terribly because CoreAnimation is apparently really slow at animating windows this way (NSViewAnimation also failed). Surprisingly not much writing on this on the web either suggesting no one does this or they aren't having performance problems.

The other thoughts I have left are making a fullscreen transparent window and animating NSViews inside the window (using CoreAnimation) or doing a fullscreen transparent OpenGL context with sprites.

What are the other options or is there some way to make CA animate windows fluidly? This should be easy with CoreAnimation so I'm confused. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on this for months until I found this link to an example:

http://www.cimgf.com/2008/03/15/core-animation-tutorial-dashboard-effect/

The basic solution which works best is to use a fullscreen transparent window and CALayers exclusively (without shadows if possible) and animate only those layers. Using NSView's or NSWindow's will not work.

You could achieve the same performance I believe by setting up a 2D OpenGL context in a transparent window but that would be more overhead. Similarly SpriteKit or Cocos2D would likely be the same equivalent of pure CALayers or OpenGL contexts.